# AWS Athena CAST with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table in Athena AWS with a timestamp field. I want to group them by date. My SQL query is:

`SELECT CAST(createdat AS DATE) FROM conversations GROUP BY createdat`
But my result is the following:
[image: asd]

As you can see the group by does not work, and the reason is that the new table has the name field `_col0` instead `createdat`. 
I also tried:
`SELECT CAST(createdat AS DATE) FROM conversations GROUP BY _col0` but I got and error.

Does anybody has any suggestions? I will appreciate it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using then same in group by

```
SELECT CAST(createdat AS DATE) 
FROM conversations 
GROUP BY CAST(createdat AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Same but a little shorter

```
SELECT CAST(createdat AS DATE) 
FROM conversations 
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Try suggesting that improvement on the given answer, (esp. since "brevity of SQL code" is not of much importance).

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is pretty old but would like to answer the reason why it failed at the first place.

Athena follows the same standard ANSI SQL convention, which defines a standard in processing an SQL query. Below is the order of processing

1. FROM clause
2. WHERE clause
3. GROUP BY clause
4. HAVING clause
5. SELECT clause
6. ORDER BY clause

From above, we can see the GROUP BY clause is processed before the SELECT clause, so the alias is not known when the GROUP BY clause is evaluated.

Any of other two answers i.e. either a column number (AFAIK it starts from 1) or full function **CAST(createdat AS DATE)** will work.

```
SELECT CAST(createdat AS DATE) 
FROM conversations 
GROUP BY 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT CAST(createdat AS DATE) 
FROM conversations 
GROUP BY CAST(createdat AS DATE);
```